# CCWave action on sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm trying to use CCWaves action, but it turns my screen into black, any suggestions to  solve this problem?

```
id myWave = [CCWaves actionWithWaves:10 amplitude:7 horizontal:YES vertical:YES grid:ccg(25,20) duration:60];

[sprite runAction: [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: myWave]];
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `AppDelegate`, make sure your EAGL depthformat is 0:

```
EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                    ];
```

Comment: I am very confused as to how I down-voted this question. It says I did it an hour ago, but I've never even read this question! Anyway, if you edit your answer, it will allow me to un-down-vote it. ;)

Comment: @ChrisCooper The mysteries of the Interbox ey? Thanks for not just ignoring it. =]